# How to use state_publisher launch file

Tags: joint-state-publisher, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to solve most of my problems, but the missing thing with me is with the CMakeLists.txt of the hand_pub. (BTW should I edit it for the hand_urdf ??)
I have added the following in my CMakeLists.txt, is there any thing I should add?

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs)
> catkin_package()
> include_directories(include
> ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> > add_executable(state_publisher
> > state_publisher.cpp)
> > target_link_libraries(state_publisher
> > ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

Because I am getting an error when trying catkin_make. I am not sure if my cpp file is wrong or it is not able to compile at all.

**my old post:**

I have finished my URDF file and saved it in catkin_ws/src/hand/hand_urdf/urdf (its name is hand.urdf)
I was able to open it in rviz using :

> roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=Hand.urdf gui:=True

(the current directory being the one stated above) and everything works and I can move the hand and everything using the state_publisher gui.
Then I worked on the state_publisher, I did the state_publisher.cpp and saved it in catkin_ws/src/hand/hand_pub and wrote a launch file called display.launch and saved it in catkin_ws/src/hand/hand_pub/launch
I think I have something wrong with my launch file which is:

> 

My question is do I have something wrong with the directories? Do I have something wrong with my launch file? Most importantly how do I run everything together from terminal (I think that I have to run the launch file but what is the exact command for that) i.e. for the urdf I called roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=Hand.urdf gui:=True.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187740/how-to-use-state_publisher-launch-file/) by [Kaddoura](https://answers.ros.org/users/19771/kaddoura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-25**:
If you are getting an error, please post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also need to upload the urdf to the parameter server. Do this by adding the following line to your launch file.

`<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find hand_urdf)/urdf/hand.urdf" />`

(assuming that I'm reading your directories correctly)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaddoura](https://answers.ros.org/users/19771/kaddoura/) on 2014-07-24**:
Thank you for your help, now I am getting an error when compiling the state_publisher.cpp file using CMakeLists, please check my post after I edited it and see if you can help me.